# How can I send a 4 byte header from Java and read it in Python?

Tags: java, python, tcp, arrays

I am trying to send a message via TCP sockets from a Java application and read it in Python 2.7
I want the first 4 bytes to specify the message length, so I could do:

```
header = socket.recv(4)
message_length = struct.unpack(">L",header)
message = socket.recv(message_length)
```

on the Python end.

Java side:

```
out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new StreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(message_length).array();
String header = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
String message_w_header = header.concat(message);
out.print(message_w_header);
```

This works for some message lengths (10, 102 characters) but for others it fails (for example 1017 characters). In the case of failing value if I output the values of each bytes I get:

```
Java:
Bytes 0 0 3 -7
Length 1017
Hex string 3f9

Python:
Bytes 0 0 3 -17
Length 1007
Hex string \x00\x00\x03\xef
```

I think this has something to do with signed bytes in Java and unsigned in Python but I can't figure out what should I do to make it work.

Comment: In the Java code, what is the type of `out`?

Comment: PrintWriter, edited code.

Comment: Are you sure python is using UTF-8 ?

Comment: Changing default encoding doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You can't decode arbitrary binary (raw 32-bit integer) as UTF-8. Instead of putting the message length into a `String`, put the message and header into a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is on Java side -- `b'\x03\xf9'` is not valid utf-8 byte sequence:

```
>>> b'\x03\xf9'.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

It seems `new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));` uses `'replace'` error handler `b'\xef'` is the first of three bytes of `'\ufffd'` Unicode replacement character encoded in utf-8:

```
>>> b'\x03\xf9'.decode('utf-8', 'replace').encode('utf-8')
b'\x03\xef\xbf\xbd'
```

that is why you receive `b'\x03\xef'` instead of `b'\x03\xf9'` in Python.

To fix it, send bytes in Java instead of Unicode text.

Unrelated, `sock.recv(n)` may return less than `n` bytes. If the socket is blocking; you could create a file-like object using `file = sock.makefile('rb')` and call `file.read(n)` to read exactly `n` bytes.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It seems that I mislead myself by assuming that there should be a 'magical' way to do it with character streams, given that they were introduced later in Java.